# React= Passing Props not working. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dataflow

As you may get from the title, passing props in react is not working. And i don´t get why.

Main App Component

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Product from './Product';

    function App() {
    return (
     <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>

        <Product name="Amazon Echo" description="Your AI assistant" price={59.99} />
        {/* Product name, description, price */}
     </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;


    OTHER COMPONENTS

    import React from 'react'

    function Product(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <h2>{props.description}</h2>
        <h3>{props.price}</h3>
      </div>
     );
   }

   export default Product;
```

Comment: Your code works as a bare example, can you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-currying-q0ejbj?file=/src/Product.js

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```js
function Product(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <h2>{props.description}</h2>
      <h3>{props.price}</h3>
    </div>
   );
}
    
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <Product name="Amazon Echo" description="Your AI assistant" price={59.99} />
  </div>
  );
}
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply... I have tried severally but am still getting a black white page.

Comment: @Palito please share full code, so we can debug.

Answer (score -1):

If you're exporting a Product component from its file then the above code should work.
Here is a sample code I created for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-shape-lqtbye?file=/src/App.js